# Opening multiple read only files in vim

Tags: vim, readonly

Is it possible from within a vim session to open multiple files all in read only mode? I've tried the following but only one of the files is opened read only.

```
:args +se\ readonly *.sql
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seemed to work for me, but I didn't test it thoroughly. I switched buffers for all the files I tested and they were all `readonly`.

```
:args *.sql | argdo set readonly
```

Alternatively, you can do `vim -R file.sql` on the command-line.

You can also open a single file with `:view`, which opens the file in `readonly`.

Comment: It is not working properly in my vim editor, If i made change and save i can't say error, and the readonly mode is opened for last file only.

Comment: Maybe try `:args *.sql | execute 'argdo view'`. If you already have a file open that will match the `*.sql`, then it will reopen that file, but the `readonly` will only take affect when you switch buffers, e.g. `:b 2`. Also, since these files are `readonly`, you can't save them.

Comment: May already opened file is treated in read only mode but currently opened .sql file are in normal mode only.

Comment: The execute is unnecessary. `:args *.sql | argdo set readonly`